# What does "e" mean in this function definition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I pass an additional parameter to this function?

```
$("#foold").click( function(e) {
  // CODE
};
```

For example, I need to pass some X value to this function. Can I write something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(X)" id="fooId">Foo</a>
```

to pass value in this function through `e` or some other way?

Comment: How to pass params: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function

Comment: No. e in that context is the event object that is populated when the event callback is executed. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @sergio-michels pls write your comment as answer - I'll mark it as best.

Comment: @xander27 ok, posted as answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here, `e` is an event object, as defined here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Yes you can pass data to the handler, using this form for the click function:

```
.click( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )

eventData             A map of data that will be passed to the event handler.
handler(eventObject)  A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
```

It will be accessible as `e.data` in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

In this link you can see how to pass params to the `JQuery click` function [jQuery's .click - pass parameters to user function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

Basically

> It allows you to pass a data map to the event object that
>   automatically gets fed back to the event handler function by jQuery as
>   the first parameter.