# How to pass argument to a jquery function through an onClick event?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery .click pass parameters to user function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

```
    $('#topleft').click(function (x) {
    loadPopupBox();
    $("#popupinner").load('getdetail.php?id=' +x);
    });
```

How to pass a value to the variable x from an onclick event? The value of the variable x is POSTED to getdetail.php and the data returned from the getdetail.php is loaded to a DIV with ID popupinner. Now everything works except the data POST/GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) syntax as `.click( [eventData], handler(eventObject) )`.

See below,

```
//                    v- Pass data
$('#topleft').click({x:x}, function (event) {
    loadPopupBox();
    $("#popupinner").load('getdetail.php?id=' + event.data.x); //read data from event obj
});
```

The [eventData] `x` can be accessed as `event.data.x`

Answer (score 0):

You can provide eventData to the [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function :

```
$('#topleft').click({x:x}, function (e) {
    loadPopupBox();
    $("#popupinner").load('getdetail.php?id=' +e.datax);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// say your selector and click handler looks something like this...
$("some selector").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, cool_function);

// in your function, just grab the event object and go crazy...
function cool_function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

As seen in [jQuery's .click - pass parameters to user function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [click event handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function) to know about how it works actually.

Comment: this should propably be a comment instead as in "Possible duplicate of..." or similar