# Problems with global variable Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, mouseevent

So I am trying to make script when u press for example "1" then click mouse to send position of cursor,  but i have problems with global variables and functions namely with `mX` and `mY`

```
$('#A').on("mousemove", function (e) {  mX = e.pageX });
$('#A').on("mousemove", function (e) {  mY = e.pageY });
...
else if (code == 49) {f(vX, vY, mX, mY);}
...
function f(vX, vY, mX, mY) {
$('#A').click(function (e) {
    var dX = Math.abs(vX - mX); <<< Here is the problem the mX is not defined
    var dY = Math.abs(vY - mY);
});
```

The problem line i singed as `<<<` i can't come with up how to solve it, i have make the variables in function to global.

Do not pay attention about `code`, `vX`, `vY` theese variables are working fine!

Comment: You realize you can get `pageX` and `pageY` in the click handler ?

Comment: Oh man, thats a lots of line of code that working together, i will do this tomorrow, now i am not able to do this, Sorry

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1fgwhqj9/

Comment: Oh, its looks like i am very silly, i will try it tomorrow, Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to 
    [How to pass argument to a jquery function through an onClick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375308/how-to-pass-argument-to-a-jquery-function-through-an-onclick-event)

```
function f(vX, vY, mX, mY) {
    $('#A').click({mX:mX, mY:mY}, function (e) {
        var dX = Math.abs(vX - e.data.mX);
        var dY = Math.abs(vY - e.data.mY);
    });
```

hope that's good for you

bye

Comment: I guess that's not good enough since the event handler only has access to the values that  `mX` and `mY` had at the moment the handler was bound.