# Returning a variable to use within another function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, global, increment

I'm making an image gallery, when I click a button I can scroll through to the next image.

I also have the option to 'jump' to a specific image. This all works fine.

However, if I scroll regularly to image 3, then jump to image 7. Once I click the next button, I don't go to image 8 as I would like to - I go to image 4. Because there are two separate functions, and I can't/ don't know how to pass the variable between them. I understand I can use a global variable outside of both functions, but this seems to be discouraged.

Here's an example:

```
var i = 0;
// i is a global variable

$("#next_button").click(function(){
   $(".all_images").eq(i).show();
   i++;
});
```

This would correctly increment through all of my images.

```
$(".thumbnails").click(function(){
    var x = $(this).index();
    $(".all_images:visible").hide();
    $(".all_images").eq(x).show();

i = x;
});
```

This shows the image relative to the thumbnail I have clicked.

So, how do I use the 'i' variable from the first function in the second function? This has always confused me. It just seems simpler to use a global variable so each function can change the value of i and use it when necessary. Please enlighten me.

Also, as I understand it's possible to wrap JQuery code in a regular JavaScript functions. It seems, however, that my code doesn't work when I wrap a JQuery .click in a regular JavaScript function (ie my_Function(){ ....$("#something").click....   }

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: please explain in short

Comment: Set a jsfiddle to describe your problem

Comment: This should work - you should create a jsFiddle, supply more code or a live dev site if you have one.

Comment: Sorry guys, it's a really simple query but looks like I've confused it. Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywXEm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options as in most programming languages:

1. Use a global variable (higher scope),
2. Pass by reference.

However, you can't really escaoe creating some kind of global variable (object or primitive) so I would suggest you make an object (maybe even key-value) that holdes all your program parameters.

In order to do this you could use the .data method like this to assign data to an arbitrary element:

```
setter : 
$('body').data('myvar','value');

getter:
$('body').data('myvar');
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

In order to pass by reference, you need to pass a object instead of a primitive.
See following link(s) for more details:

- [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)
- http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass
- [jQuery's .click - pass parameters to user function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. I'll have a read through the links. In a small script, is this really necessary? It seems like overkill when all I need is a single global variable to keep track of a value that can be changed by multiple functions.

Comment: For one variable it does seem a bit like overkill in my opinion. Usually .data is used for more complicated scripts to avoid fugly code.

Comment: I'll stick with a global variable in this case then. Thank you very much for your answer.