# Jquery Plugin Respond to events in Selector

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm writing a plugin to sort a table.  When someone clicks on the TH it sorts the column.

So my Jquery would be something like"

```
$("#TableID").AddSorting();
```

I'm not sure how to reference the sorting function in the Plugin.  Without the plugin I'm doing the below.

```
 <th data-sort="LastName, FirstName">
   <a onclick="SortTheGrid("FirstName, LastName");">First Name</a>
 </th>
```

Maybe in the plugin I can just do:

```
 $this.find("th[data-sort] a").click(function(){...});
```

thanks Chuck

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery's [click functionality](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

e.g.,

```
function doSort () {
    //your sort code here
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#YourButtonName").click(function () { doSort(); });
});
```

You still need to pass arguments into your click handler, so it knows which columns to sort by. There's details of how to pass parameters to a jQuery click event handler in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function).