# How do I attach a function to an event handler with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm writing in jQuery and want to make something happen when an element is clicked. The function I want called requires parameters, and the event must be watched for at all times, so the handler is in $(document).ready(). Here's what I mean:

```
"use strict"
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<button>").each(
        $(this).click(doSomething)
    );    
});
function doSomething(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

The problem is that doSomething needs a message that it can alert. However, were I to change the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<button>").each(
        $(this).click(doSomething("Hello world"))
    );    
});
function doSomething(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

Then "Hello world" would be alerted when the page loads, and clicking buttons would do nothing. How do I keep the behavior of the first way, but pass the method a parameter?

Comment: I guess you have erroneous usage of `.each()` and problems with jQuery selector (you basically create new `<button>` element).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to pass an anonymous function which then calls your function with the required argument:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
            doSomething("Hello world!");
        });
    );    
});
function doSomething(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

Note that I've modified the selector so that it selects existing `<button>` elements rather than creating a new one, and removed the unnecessary `.each()` since `.click()` implicitly iterates over the matched elements already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  $("button").click(function(){
        doSomething("Hello world");
    });
    function doSomething(message){
        alert(message);
    }
```

Comment: You're right, it work but .each isn't needed, i edit the message.

Answer (score 0):

You need the bind-function. This is a recent addition to ECMAScript and you would need to provide it in case it's not available:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1), 
        fToBind = this, 
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Check this page for a reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

If you include this code you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(doSomething.bind("Hello world"));
});
function doSomething(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

Comment: `.each()` will never work in that way + `$("<button>")` will create new element rather than select the existing one.

Answer (score -1):

You have a number of errors in your code,
first of all `$("<button>")` creates new dom element rather then selecting existing on page elements.
Regarding this piece `doSomething("Hello world")` - You are immediately evaling the code, in Jquery click [reference](http://api.jquery.com/click/) you can see that data to handler has to go as the first parameter. Here's the proper listing

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("button").each(
        $(this).click("Hello world",doSomething)
    );    
});
function doSomething(message){
    alert(message);
}
```