# Parameter in a jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I want to pass an object called `hotTraitement` in parameters of an event `.click` of jquery. So I declare my object like this :

```
$(window).load(function(){
        container = document.getElementById('tab_traitement');
        var hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {
            data: data_traitement});
});
```

And I'm trying to pass this object like this :

```
$('#submit_button_traitement').click(function({hotTraitement:hotTraitement})
{
    console.log(hotTraitement);
});
```

But it's not working, `hotTraitement` is undefined.

Help please !

Comment: Why woudl you even want to do that? hotTraitement is a variable which is accessible from inside your click callback... Why not just access it from there?

Comment: Furthermore, this question is a possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function

Comment: @dangor I already looked this question and it's what I'm trying to do, but doesn't work. And it's really complicate, I want to get this object to use it in an ajax callback, so I need to pass this object

Comment: your code is awesome but just one thing as i said before just create your hotTraitement var outside this line $(window).load(function(){

Comment: Each time I try something, I try inside the window.load AND outside it.

Comment: its really weird because its working for me in my browser ... if you wanna see js fiddle example i can do for you ... but its really working

Comment: ok here see an example
http://jsfiddle.net/ohcdxgby/

Comment: I know it is weird ^^ I work on this problem for 2 weeks, no way, I don't find the answer

Comment: I use an object, and you use a string. Maybe it doesn't work the same way :/

Comment: check console.log(hotTraitement) what is console saying ???

Comment: Undefined ... Weird, because my object is displayed

Comment: Is `data_traitement` defined ?

Comment: Yes, it's an array and I can get the value with console.log

Comment: i think your code
var hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {data: data_traitement});
just making hotTraitement  var to undefine or null ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Define the `hotTraitement` variable as global one.

```
$('#submit_button_traitement').click({hotTraitement:hotTraitement},function(e){
   console.log(e.data.hotTraitement);
});
```

SIMPLE DEMO: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDGXA/1063/)

**Update:**

Try this way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('tab_traitement');
  var hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data_traitement
  });

  //...

  $('#submit_button_traitement').click({
    hotTraitement: hotTraitement
  }, function(e) {
    console.log(e.data.hotTraitement);
  });

});
```

Comment: It stays undefined :/

Comment: Did you define this `hotTraitement` variable globally?

Comment: I think. I'm outside the window.load.

Comment: In your fiddle, you use a simple string, and I'm using an object. Maybe it's different ?

Comment: It didn't work with my code but I tried to do it in an other page, with the same code but simplified and it worked. So I used your method on the real code and it didn't work. So I had something in the options of the declaration of my handsontable (hotTraitement) which blocked what I want. I modify what was wrong, and now, every things work fine! Thanks to you ! (2 weeks to finally find a solution, you're my hero ! ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `$(document).ready()` for `$(window).load()` ; utilizing `.on()` , `data` property of `event`

```js
$(document).ready([
  function() {
    // define `hotTraitement`
    hotTraitement = {
      "abc": 123
    };
  }, 
  function() {
    // set `event.data` to `hotTraitement`
    $("#submit_button_traitement")
    .on("click", hotTraitement, function(event) {
        // do stuff with `event.data` : `hotTraitement`
        console.log(event.data)
    })
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="submit_button_traitement">click</div>
```

Comment: your code will give an error like

Uncaught ReferenceError: hotTraitment is not defined

Comment: It's right, hotTraitement is undefined with your code :/

Comment: @Lison Tried substituting `$(document).ready()` for `$(window).load()` ?

Comment: @Lison _"It's not working :/"_ Can describe "It's not working" ? Tried `js`  at stacksnippets ?

Answer (score 0):

why you want to pass hotTraitement parameter in onclick function instead you can simply access this inside your onclick even like this

```
$(window).load(function(){
    container = document.getElementById('tab_traitement');
    var hotTraitement = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: data_traitement});

   $('#submit_button_traitement').click(function(){
      console.log(hotTraitement);
   });
});
```

Comment: But it doesn't work. I get an object but I can't apply the method that I want.

Comment: then simply in your way don't create hotTraitement object inside window load method just simple add this lines outside window load function this will work for you  ....

Comment: how ? because in JSFIDDLE it is working ...
just create your hotTraitement object before click event and outside of everything