# How to store a value inside a jquery function to use it later in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function where i am getting a value i want to use that value to some other function .How to achieve that??

```
jQuery.getJSON(url+"&startDate="+startDate+"&endDate="+endDate+"&jobId="+jobId+"&type="+type, function(data) {  

        if(data.searchResultArray.length>0){
        for(var z=0; z<data.searchResultArray.length;z++){  

            searchResultArray = data.searchResultArray[z].split("$$##$$##");
            createTable = createTable + "<tr><td>"+searchResultArray[0]+"</td><td><a href =#  onclick=addPresentCandidatePopUp(searchResultArray[4]);  target=\"_self\">"+searchResultArray[1]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[2]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[3]+"</td></tr>";

            candidateId= (searchResultArray[4]);
```

This candidateId i am storing in a variable and later i  want to  use inside another function.
How to do that.Please somebody help

Comment: you could probalby add a global variable and access this global variable from the other function: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Why not using localstorage or cookies or global variable?

Comment: create hidden input with value of your variable in function and get it using jquery in another function

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a global variable for it?

```
var newVariable = [];

jQuery.getJSON(url+"&startDate="+startDate+"&endDate="+endDate+"&jobId="+jobId+"&type="+type, function(data) {  

if(data.searchResultArray.length>0){
for(var z=0; z<data.searchResultArray.length;z++){  

searchResultArray = data.searchResultArray[z].split("$$##$$##");
createTable = createTable + "<tr><td>"+searchResultArray[0]+"</td><td><a href =#  onclick=addPresentCandidatePopUp(searchResultArray[4]);  target=\"_self\">"+searchResultArray[1]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[2]+"</td><td>"+searchResultArray[3]+"</td></tr>";

candidateId= (searchResultArray[4]);
newVariable.push(candidateId);
```

Comment: its a jQuery function how to pass value to it $(".saveToDB").click(function() {

Comment: You should have mentioned this part in your question as well. But anyways, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function) is how you pass a function to jQuery.

Comment: i want to pass that candidateId to that $(".saveToDB").click(function() {

Comment: how to get value from newVariable??