# How do I create a <p> tag dynamically and assign it to a var when I click it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I create a `<p>` tag dynamically and assign it to a var when I click it, it should go to a function `goTo` and know in what `<p>` I clicked, in order to access the index of the array `lastGoals`.

And I have other problem, it is 30 in "30s" I do this function to update and when I click it call the function many times I updated with this function.
I know the `i` is not in the scope of `$(document).on();` there is other problem because if I put inside the `for` it will be addind the click in a bad way I think.

```
var isFirstTime = true;
var text = '<p class="boxLastGoals">test</p>';
var size = lastGoals.length;
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   if (isFirstTime) {
   $('#listLastGoals').html(text);
      isFirstTime = false;
    } else {
       $('#listLastGoals').append(text);
    }
}

$(document).on('click', 'p.boxLastGoals', goTo(event, i));
```

Comment: `goTo(event, i)` will invoke the function.. You are suppose to pass function as an argument..Value of `i` will be last value in the `loop`

Comment: But I cannot put the `.on` inside the loop.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: Its hard because it more complex that i demonstrate here I cuted a lot of parts

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/atg5m6ym/2036/

Comment: Like i said i cuted a lot of things to be more simply and it is equals in this to be there or not but i will change to put outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are happy using JQuery you can use JQuery to create the `<p>` element for you inside the loop and attach the click handler dynamically in there. You can also attach the data to the element using the `.prop('value', 'test');` method so it can be accessed inside the click handler like `$(this).prop('value');`.

I've updated my example to include a loop and access a variable to match your scenario

**Example**

*HTML*

```
<div id="content">  
</div>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = ['goal 1', 'goal 2', 'goal 3', 'goal 4', 'goal 5'];

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var text = list[i];
    var pEl = $('<p></p>', {
      text: text
    });

    pEl.prop('arrayIndex', i);
    pEl.on('click', function(e) {
      goToGoal(e, $(this).prop('arrayIndex'));
    });

    $('#content').append(pEl);
  }
});

function goToGoal(e, i) {
  alert('go to goal: ' + i);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2039/) to demonstrate

Comment: When i refresh it calls the function that i call in all iteration of the `for`.

`$(document).ready(function() {
                var pEl = $('<p></p>', {
                    text: text
                }).on('click', goToGoal(event, i));`

Comment: It should only call the `goToGoal` function once per element. I'm going to update my answer again because to remember values you will need to attach them to the element using `prop()`

Comment: I followed you example but with this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquerys-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquerys-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function)

Comment: Message me I dont know where to start the chat :)

Comment: Not entirely sure how to do it but heres a link for a chat room ive created http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/107123/dynamically-create-p-tag?tab=general

Comment: Yeah i putted to work with your example not strict but with mostly but i dont know how to change this `var pEl = $('<p></p>', {
                    text: text
                }` because is showing the tags and not interpreting. And sorry for my english.

Comment: Maybe this link will work http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107123/dynamically-create-p-tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107125/discussion-between-tiago-sousa-and-will-harris).