# How to bind an argument to a jquery callback without affecting this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript/jquery and here's the example code I need help with:

```js
function add(text) {
  $(this).replaceWith('<label>'+text+'</label>');
}

var label = 'Added';
$('#myDiv').append($('<button type="button">Add</button>').click(function() {
  add.call(this, label);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Is there a "better" way of setting the `click` callback here?

If the add function did not have a `text` argument, I could have easily used `.click(add)` and the button will be bound automatically as `this`.

But with the argument, I can't bind `text` without having to set the value of `this` too i.e. `.click(add.bind(this, label))` would be wrong as `this` is set to the global context.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at [`.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and its `data` parameter.

Comment: @Andreas –I was thinking of [`jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

Comment: @Andreas: That (with a bit more detail and example) would make a very good "here's the jQuery way" answer.

Comment: @Andreas: Looks like a duplicate to me, good find. I'll move my answer there, surprisingly there's no "curry" answer there that I see.

Comment: @Andreas: Oh, wait, my bad -- that question doesn't have the `this` aspect to it.

Comment: zhaomin - The question Andreas was referring to (since his comment was auto-deleted) was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquerys-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) points out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671613/how-to-bind-an-argument-to-a-jquery-callback-without-affecting-this#comment64723697_38671613), there's a solution to this that's specific to jQuery event handlers: The `data` argument to the [`on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on).

More generally, though, what you're looking for is sometimes called "currying" (or "partial application;" purists tell me one of them is technically incorrect but I can never remember which).

I have a function I use for that which I add to `Function.prototype`; it looks like this *(see comments)*:

```
(function() {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
        value: function() {
            // Remember the original function and the arguments we wre called with
            var f = this,
                curried = slice.call(arguments);
            // Return a new function
            return function() {
                // Our function was called, add in any arguments it was called with...
                var args = curried.concat(slice.call(arguments));
                // ...and call the original, passing along `this`
                return f.apply(this, args);
            };
        }
    });
})();
```

In your case, you'd use it like this:

```
var label = 'Added';
$('#myDiv').append($('<button type="button">Add</button>').click(add.curry(label)));
```

Note that your `add` function will be called with the value of `label` (as it was when we made the `curry` call, not as it is later), followed by any arguments that the curried function was called with (e.g., the event object).

Example:

```js
(function() {
  var slice = Array.prototype.slice;

  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "curry", {
    value: function() {
      // Remember the original function and the arguments we wre called with
      var f = this,
        curried = slice.call(arguments);
      // Return a new function
      return function() {
        // Our function was called, add in any arguments it was called with...
        var args = curried.concat(slice.call(arguments));
        // ...and call the original, passing along `this`
        return f.apply(this, args);
      };
    }
  });
})();

function add(text) {
  console.log("add called with text = '" + text + "'");
}
var label = 'Added';
$('#myDiv').append($('<button type="button">Add</button>').click(add.curry(label)));
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```