# Replace a button with another using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a little problem that I tried to solve without success and I hope you guys could help me .

So I have a button that once clicked should call an Ajax function and replace itself with the response gotten from the Ajax on success .

My code so far for the html :

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-white btn-xs" onclick="like(83,1)">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
 J'aime !
</button>
</div>
```

and the jquery part :

```
function like(id, t) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/likes.php?postID=" + id + "&likeID=" + t,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#button" + t).replaceWith(data);
        }

    });
}
```

Clicking & calling the Ajax function works and I can see the response with the required HTML from the developer console but the original one doesn't get replaced with it .

The response looks like that :

```
<button id='button1' class='btn btn-white btn-xs 1' onclick='like(83,1)'>
<i class='fa fa-heart'></i>
 J'aime plus         
</button>
```

Thanks !

Comment: Could you please console.log(data) and check you are getting correct response? If you are getting correct one then can you try $.parseHTML(data) within your replacewith code.

Comment: thanks vijayP, the $.parseHTML(data) worked like charm for me !

Comment: thats great @Anass...!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the onclick attribute, I suggest you try using jQuery's click().

Perhaps you may try the following structure,

```
var ids; //set equal to number of id's in total

for (let i = 0; i < ids; i++) {
    $("button" + i).click({id: 83}, function() {
        callback(i, event.data.id);
    }
}
...
function callback(i,t){
  return function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax/likes.php?postID=" + t + "&likeID=" + i,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
            $("#button" + i).replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

edit: there is a way to pass params through click(). See [jQuery's .click - pass parameters to user function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquerys-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function) for a far more thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks but i can't use the jQuery's click() because i have many buttons that got generated with different ids and i must pass parameters to the function to know which one is clicked and replace it with the proper code

Comment: the button id ( id="button1" ) may get different numbers like button2 button3 button4 , if you got an idea and how to get that works will appreciate it . thanks

Comment: Just updated the answer again. It makes the assumption that button id suffixes are in numerical order. If there are gaps in the data (i.e. 1,2,3,5,9), then I would recommend throwing all button id values into an array and iterating through that. I also assumed that 't' was the value by which id suffixes are tracked, considering "button1" had t set to 1.

Comment: i appreciate your efforts, but if the user click the same button 2 times the code will assume that it's for the next button as the i is incremented on each click !

Comment: Right. Using a callback should fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

## The same code

Please check the value of the variable `t` inside the `ajax.success`.

```js
var buttonsPlus = ["<button id='button1' class='btn btn-white btn-xs' onclick='like(83,1)'>\n\r<i class='fa fa-heart'></i> \nJ'aime plus\n</button>","<button id='button2' class='btn btn-white btn-xs' onclick='like(83,2)'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i> David plus</button>"];

function like(likes, index){
  // simulate ajax call
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#button'+index).replaceWith(buttonsPlus[index-1]);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
<button id="button1" class="btn btn-white btn-xs" onclick="like(83,1)">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
 J'aime !
</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn btn-white btn-xs" onclick="like(83,2)">
<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
 David !
</button>
</div>
```

## EDIT #2:

Try to change the `ajax.dataType` from `html` to `text/plain`